# Laravel raw query with relationship methods defined within the model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I've created a function that executes a raw query (for a search form). This returns the query-result like `return \DB::Select(\DB::Raw("SELECT ..."))` The model which holds this method also contains relationship functions. Let's say this model has a relationship function `products` and the results from the raw query are stored in $items.

When I try something like

```
@foreach($items as $item)
  @foreach($item->products as $product)
    {{ $product->someVar }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I get a undefined property "Undefined property: stdClass::products" error. I assume this is because Laravel doesn't know yet that $items in fact is a collection of the Model-class that has the relationship with "products".

Is there a way to "bind" those relationship functions to a raw query?

Comment: Show us some more code how you populate ``$items`` array

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution kinda unknowingly where to look in de Model-class. There's a method `hydrate` (and `hydrateRaw`). The documentation tells us the following about it:

> "Create a collection of models from plain arrays."

In case anyone is wondering, this is how to fix the problem above:

```
return self::hydrate(
  \DB::Select(
    \DB::Raw("SELECT * FROM `table`")
  )
);
```